# Pydantic best option to initialize deribed fields in a model

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

I define a BaseModel class to represent a grid dataset based on the `path` to the dataset file. My problem is that I want to make an initial load in memory of this dataset to extract some properties and store them as fields of the object. To perform this process only one time, now I am using a `@model_validator(mode="after")` to override optional fields that I declare but I suppose there are proper ways to do this because is really confusing for users to see a class with so many input fields when only one is required.

See the example, below:

```py
class Grid(BaseModel):
    """class to manage TESEO's grid
    
    Attributes:
        path (str): path to grid-file
    """

    path: str
    """path to grid-file""" 
    dx: float = None
    """cell size in x-direction"""
    dy: float = None
    """cell size in y-direction"""
    nx: int = None
    """number of cells in x-direction"""
    ny:int = None
    """number of cells in y-direction"""
    bbox: tuple[float, float, float, float] = None
    """bounding box of the grid (lon_min, lat_min, lon_max, lat_max)"""
    nan_value: float = -999
    """value to be considered as NaN"""

    @model_validator(mode="after")
    def compute_grid_properties(self):
        df = read_grid(self.path, self.nan_value)
        self.bbox = (df.lon.min(), df.lat.min(), df.lon.max(), df.lat.max())
        self.dx, self.nx = _calculate_cell_properties(df, COORDINATE_NAMES["x"])
        self.dy, self.ny = _calculate_cell_properties(df, COORDINATE_NAMES["y"])

        return self

    def load_df(self, nan_value=None):
        return read_grid(self.path, nan_value)

    def load_ds(self, nan_value=None):
        return (
            self.load_df()
            .set_index([COORDINATE_NAMES["x"], COORDINATE_NAMES["y"]])
            .to_xarray()
        )
```

Any clue how to do this properly? I expect to finally have something like:

```py
class Grid(BaseModel):
    """class to manage TESEO's grid
    
    Attributes:
        path (str): path to grid-file
    """

    path: str
    """path to grid-file""" 
    nan_value: float = -999
    """value to be considered as NaN"""

    @the_proper_decorator_or_different_way
    def compute_grid_properties(self):
        df = read_grid(self.path, self.nan_value)
        self.bbox = (df.lon.min(), df.lat.min(), df.lon.max(), df.lat.max())
        self.dx, self.nx = _calculate_cell_properties(df, COORDINATE_NAMES["x"])
        self.dy, self.ny = _calculate_cell_properties(df, COORDINATE_NAMES["y"])

        return self

    def load_df(self, nan_value=None):
        return read_grid(self.path, nan_value)

    def load_ds(self, nan_value=None):
        return (
            self.load_df()
            .set_index([COORDINATE_NAMES["x"], COORDINATE_NAMES["y"]])
            .to_xarray()
        )
```

Any help is really appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need the type validation for `dx`, `dy`, `bbox` etc.?

Comment: No. The user will never declare this fields. they are calculated from the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you propose in your second code block is not possible with Pydantic, because all public attributes have to be declared as fields. So you either have the option to declare those as fields or work with a private data attribute and expose the data using properties.

I think the cleanest solution is something along the lines of:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, model_validator, validate_call
    

def read_grid_properties(path, nan_value=-999):
    """Read grid properties from file"""
    # Read grid properties from file
    bbox = (0, 0, 1, 1)
    dx = 1
    nx = 1
    dy = 1
    ny = 1
    return bbox, dx, nx, dy, ny


class GridProperties(BaseModel):
    """Grid properties"""
    bbox: tuple[float, float, float, float] = Field(frozen=True)
    dx: float = Field(frozen=True)
    nx: int = Field(frozen=True)
    dy: float = Field(frozen=True)
    ny: int = Field(frozen=True)

    @model_validator(mode="wrap")
    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, values, handler):
        if "path" in values:
            values = dict(cls.from_path(**values))
        
        return handler(values)

    @classmethod
    @validate_call
    def from_path(cls, path: str, nan_value: float=-999):
        bbox, dx, nx, dy, ny = read_grid_properties(path, nan_value)
        return cls(bbox=bbox, dx=dx, nx=nx, dy=dy, ny=ny)
    

# This works
p = GridProperties(path=838, nan_value=-999)

# This raises an error
#p.dx = 42

# This works as well but will not be used...
GridProperties(bbox=(0, 0, 1, 1), dx=1, nx=1, dy=1, ny=1)
```

This clarifies the intention of the relevant in memory data being `dx`, `dy`, `bbox` etc., which is just instanced from a path and fill value for NaNs. By freezing the field you clarify those are read only after init. In addition the simple constructor of `GridProperties(path="", nan_value=-999)` works as intended and the data is still validated.

Alternatively you can work with regular properties:

```py
class Grid(BaseModel):
    """class to manage TESEO's grid
    
    Attributes:
        path (str): path to grid-file
    """

    path: str
    """path to grid-file""" 
    nan_value: float = -999
    """value to be considered as NaN"""

    # Private attribute
    _data = ()

    @property
    def dx(self):
        """Cell size in x-direction"""
        return self._data[1]
    
    @property
    def nx(self):
        """Number of cells in x-direction"""
        return self._data[2]
    
    @property
    def dy(self):
        """Cell size in y-direction"""
        return self._data[3]
    
    @property
    def ny(self):
        """Number of cells in y-direction"""
        return self._data[4]
    
    @property
    def bbox(self):
        """Bounding box"""
        return self._data[0]

    def model_post_init(self, __context):
        """Read grid properties from file"""
        self._data = read_grid_properties(self.path, self.nan_value)


g = Grid(path="")
```

I hope this helps.